# Convert GPS data Cello-CANiQ

Tags: gps, hex, latitude-longitude

I'm receiving data from a GPS tracker.
Documentation says:
Byte-Aligned Table:

```
[1] -> System Code, byte 1 – ASCII "M"
[2] -> System Code, byte 2 – ASCII "C"
[3] -> System Code, byte 3 – ASCII "G"
[4] -> System Code, byte 4 – ASCII "P"
...
[45] -> Longitude
[46] -> Longitude
[47] -> Longitude
[48] -> Longitude
[49] -> Latitude
[50] -> Latitude
[51] -> Latitude
[52] -> Latitude
...
```

I've got the following (hex) data:

```
...
[45] -> 09
[46] -> 36
[47] -> 4b
[48] -> f8

[49] -> a7
[50] -> 70
[51] -> 7b
[52] -> 00
...
```

> Longitude, Latitude
>   Longitude and latitude coordinates of current position fix. Both coordinates are sent as
>   32-bit signed integers, representing the coordinates in 10 -8 radian resolution. Possible
>   values are -Π to +Π for longitude, or – Π/2 to + Π/2 for latitude. The coordinates refer to
>   WGS-84 map datum and ellipsoid.

How can I convert this to coordinates around longitude ~ -74, latitude ~4?

Answer (score 0):

I can only base my answer on what you wrote above.

What you have are two 32 bits integers, where "1" represents 10e-8 rad.

So what you can do is multiply by `1e-7` to get radians. To convert to degrees (which is usually used to represent WGS84 coordinates), multiply by `180 / pi`.

Something like this:

```
const oneRadMultiplier = 1e-7 * 180 / pi;

latitudeDeg  = 0x09364bf8 * oneRadMultiplier; 
longitudeDeg = 0xa7707b00 * oneRadMultiplier;
```

The numbers that you gave as an example don't really seem to match though. It might be that these integers are stored as little endian. I didn't try, but hopefully the above helps to get you a bit further.